# Google Nexus 5 doesn't boot

Tags: nexus-5, boot

Last night my phone was casually working when all of a sudden, the screen froze on the active application. This happened before but usually it unfreezed or restarted, but now, the phone just turned off (screen went entirely black) and doesn't respond to anything (tried to hold power button, in combination with either & both volume buttons) for about 1 minute per combination.
The phone doesn't respond to my charger being plugged in all night either...

Is there anything else I can try before having to take it back to the store?

Comment: What android version did you have?

Comment: @SuperThomasLab Android Lollipop 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you if you still have warranty to bring it back to the store.
However you maybe should read this first:
[Nexus 5 and Nexus 7 Lollipop Update Brick](http://www.vcpost.com/articles/57010/20150413/nexus-7-nexus-5-nexus-7-adroid-lollipop-update-brick-nexus-5-adroid-lollipop-update-brick.htm).

The Nexus 5 and the Nexus 7 can be bricked in lollipop, and it only can boot to the Google logo. I don't know if this is your problem but it may be a part of your problem. If you update your phone to Android 5.1 then it should be fixed.